# C++ is it possible to use command line arguments in a Metro Windows 8 Store App?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps, command-line-arguments

Ive seen several ways to launch Metro Windows 8 store app from a command line and they do work, however Ive been trying to send command line arguments by using the GetCommandLine method in the app and I cant get anything from parsing it.

```
App::App()
{
    using namespace std;
    wstring strCommandLine;
    strCommandLine = GetCommandLine();
   /*command line parser here*/
}
```

Is it possible to use commandline arguments in a Metro Windows 8 Store App?

Comment: Is parsing the arguments the problem (they are in the string returned by `GetCommandLine`) or is it passing them to the app (they are not in the returned string)?

Comment: The command line arguments are in [the `LaunchActivatedEventArgs.Arguments` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.arguments.aspx).

Comment: Great! LaunchActivatedEventArgs.Arguments does hold the argument yes, that was the problem I was having thank you!